# Getting javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

[Contains the code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5edG5.png)

2018-01-22 22:46:30,987 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2018-01-22 22:46:30,987 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2018-01-22 22:46:38,487 INFO o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: count is 3
2018-01-22 22:46:40,316 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Count for class: Script19
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:220) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:42) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:843) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error is related to one of previous executions as I fail to see `Count` property reference anywhere in your code. Clean the log window by pressing "Ctrl+E" keys combination and re-run your test.

Also make sure you tick `Cache compiled script if available` box as this way your Groovy code will perform much faster.

References:

- [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: The same code is working perfect in apache 3.0 version and i have tried all the possible combinations in apache 3.3 version but no luck and i'm sure the error is not related to count as i printed the value it captured the count of matches